# Adding sheet name to the conceited final merged sheet in excel

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge multiple excel sheets to one and to have a new column with the name of the original sheet
I'm using the following code:

```py
list_of_sheets = list(df.keys())
cdf = pd.concat(df[sheet] for sheet in list_of_sheets)

# tried 
cdf = pd.concat(df[sheet]["Brand"] for sheet in list_of_sheets)

# and
list_of_sheets = list(df.keys())
for sheet in list_of_sheets:
    df[sheet]["Brand"] = sheet
    cdf = pd.concat(df[sheet])
```

but none of them works

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you want?

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat(pd.read_excel("my_excel_file.xlsx", sheet_name=None))
```

The sheet's names will be the index of the dataframe.

Comment: I know how to merge data from multiple sheets, I want to add the sheet name to know from where the data was taken from...

Comment: If you see the result, the sheet name will become the index.

Answer (score 0):

**First read the file:**

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
```

**Which should produce the following:**

```
<pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile at 0x12cad0860>
```

Then **iterate over the sheets**, **append the sheet name as a separate column** and **store all dfs in a list**:

```
dfs = []
for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
    df = xl.parse(sheet)
    df['sheet_name'] = sheet
    dfs.append(df)
```

In order to **concat them at last**:

```
pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'parse'

Comment: I've edited the answer. You can see that `xl` should be `pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile` type, which should have the 'parse' attribute - it shouldn't be a DataFrame.